# wifi not working on lenovo g50 30

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu version Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS today and my WiFi is not working. I was using zorin os before the wifi worked fine in it. Please can anyone assist me?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you install? What is the WiFi adapter you are using?

Comment: 22.04.1 LTS  this is the ubuntu version

Comment: how do i check the wifi adapter

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)